# Sum of nilpotent and element is a unit in ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I can't tell where I went wrong, am still a beginner.

Let N be a nilpotent in a commutive ring , let X be any element.

I'll will be showing X + N is a unit .

Assume Y(X+N) =1

Then YX(N^n-1) =  N^n-1

Multiplying both side by  X+N

We get X(N^n-1) =  X(N^n-1)
 Thus nilpotent summed with any element gives unit.

Comment: The claim is false and you assumed your conclusion in the first step of the 'proof'...

Comment: Try $X = -N$, $X = 0$, and so on. The statement is true for $X = 1$.

Comment: Side question , if I assume something and the conclusions is wrong then the assumption is wrong. What about if the conclusion is right does that imply assumption is correct?

Comment: If your assumption is wrong, you can deduce *anything* from it :-)

Comment: Ya that's true. Thanks for the answers everyone.

Comment: It seems to me that people are misunderstanding my question , am not asking for the answers to the question , am asking what is wrong with my proof to make the obviously wrong statement above seem correct to me.

Comment: Also I came up with this argument which am not sure if it works or not: assume there is no unit Y , X is a unit and N is a nilpotent then YX + YN not= 1 which implies.YX(N^n-1) not= N^n-1 for all Y , a contradiction since X is a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you were mistaking the proposition and are really trying the show that the sum of a *unit* and a nilpotent is a unit. I can start you off with two methods. Let $x$ be nilpotent and let $u$ be a unit.

The first method is basic prealgebra.

Notice that $(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+ \dots 1) = x^n-1$ in any commutative ring. If $n$ is a natural number such that $x^n = 0$...

The second method involves the characterization of nilpotents in terms of ideals. It is elementary that the set of nilpotents of a ring form an ideal and this ideal is the intersection of all prime ideals of the ring (a proof is in the first chapter of Atiyah-MacDonald for instance). So suppose that $u+x$ is *not* a unit and so let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal that contains $u+x$. Since $x$ is nilpotent it is also contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ and we have [contradiction]...

Comment: It was originally about the sum of a unit and nilpotent and I did the above argument but then I realized that X does not need to be a unit so I must done something wrong but I couldn't see it.

Comment: but it does need to be a unit.